# CocoaPods frameworks: codesign is trying to use a code signing identity I've deleted

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, code-signing

I'm running into a bizarre and frustrating issue trying to code sign frameworks added by CocoaPods. Basically my situation is this: towards the start of this project I was using a development certificate called *iPhone Developer: Foo (EPVVKCMTUU)*, but I've since deleted that item from the keychain and added a new certificate called *iPhone Developer: Bar (2GET2WP9BU)*.

Now whenever I try to build my project, CocoaPods seems to be trying to use that old, deleted identity to code sign frameworks instead of the newly added one. When it reaches the *Embed Pod Frameworks* step, it errors out with the following output:

```
Code Signing /Users/rpowell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSProject-drvqqtwgdezwyfcchhsckmxcddzs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/iOSProject.app/Frameworks/Argo.framework with Identity iPhone Developer: Foo (EPVVKCMTUU)
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 9326811E6F54C4459C0C05A802F7557419C426E0 --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements /Users/rpowell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iOSProject-drvqqtwgdezwyfcchhsckmxcddzs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/iOSProject.app/Frameworks/Argo.framework
9326811E6F54C4459C0C05A802F7557419C426E0: no identity found
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved my own issue! The problem was that the original certificate hadn't been removed from the provisioning profile I was using. I deleted the developer ID in the provisioning portal, regenerated the provisioning profile, and now it works.